# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: createStackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

In my react native application I am not using stack navigator and package also removed from the dependancy. Still when I run application in ios simulator its show the error

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: createStackNavigator

Answer (score 0):

Restart your node packager

```
npm start / react-native start
```

Or try by removing cache

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

> To clean Clean deriveddata with xcode project
>
> ```
> cd ios
> xcodebuild clean
> ```
>
> Clean ios build folder
>
> ```
> rm -rf ios/build
> ```
>
> Clean ios pods
>
> ```
> rm -rf ios/Pods
> ```

Answer (score 0):

if the package is removed from package.json file, run `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you imported the package in your import statements.

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
```

Try to install `npm install @react-navigation/native-stack`
Try to install navigation package `**npm install @react-navigation/native**`

If using expo  `**expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context**`

Try to clear cache with `**npm start ----reset-cache**`